# Xpath Required : get child of sibling nodes based on the first node's child

Tags: selenium, xpath, protractor

I am new to xpath, I want to get the xpath for the below scenario.

```
<div class='wj-group wj-frozen'>
   <div class='group'>
      <p> sample header 1</p>
   </div>
</div>
<div class='wj-frozen'>
   <div class='item'>
      <p> sample item 1 </p>
   </div>
</div>
<div class='wj-frozen'>
   <div class='item'>
      <p> sample item 2 </p>
   </div>
</div>
<div class='wj-group wj-frozen'>
   <div class='group'>
      <p> sample header 2</p>
   </div>
</div>
<div class='wj-frozen'>
   <div class='item'>
      <p> sample item 1 </p>
   </div>
</div>
<div class='wj-frozen'>
   <div class='item'>
      <p> sample item 2 </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

I need to get the sample item1 & sample item 2 under the sample header1. The number of sample item's are dynamic. I may get more number of items below the sample header 1 and above the sample header 2. So that I can't use the position.

If I use following-sibling for the div - sample header1, then I am getting the result as all the sample items. I need only the sample items between the sample header1 and sample header 2. 
Anyone please give a clue on this..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show your code trials?

Comment: Let me know if you would Accept an equivalent `Java` solution.

Comment: I need it as xpath string to pass it as a locator text to find the particular ui element for selenium automation. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of struggling, found it, The solution may be little lengthy, but it works.

```
//div[@class='wj-frozen'][preceding-sibling::div[contains(.,'sample header 1')] and following-sibling::div[contains(.,'sample header 2')]]/div/p
```

it matches the items between header 1 and 2.

Comment: Thanks for your help... In real there are more child div elements in place of the tag <p> (sample header & sample item). So based on the child criteria I need to select the nodes. 
Any how I applied your logic and works fine.  As per your logic I need to know both the sample header 1 & 2 to pass it to the condition. 
But in real I will be knowing only the sample header 1. So i need to find out the next sibling node which is having the sample header(class wj-group). both the sample headers are having the common class attribute wj-group. and the sample items does not have.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you can use this (//p[text()='sample header 2']/../../preceding-sibling::div[@class='wj-frozen']/div/p)[index].

using index you can get nth element between those two elements.

NOTE: plz make sure to use the exact same text as there is in the paragraph text(include spaces if the text contains otherwise it will not work)